# Crystal Reports Conditional Rounding

Tags: crystal-reports

I just started learning Crystal Reports, and am using the below formatting formula:

```
local numberVar result;
if GroupName ({SCD_CUSTOMER.NAME}) = "32 Bar Blues, LLC" Then
(
    result = round({PTS_PRI_ORDER_PRICING.SELLING_PRICE}, 2);
    result;
)
Else defaultAttribute
```

For a while I didn't have the Else statement there, and I couldn't understand why the report would round ALL selling_price values, rather than just those for 32 Bar Blues, LLC.

Sticking the Else in fixed my issue, but I still don't understand it. Why is the round being executed when it should never even be looked at for scd_customer.name != 32 Bar Blues, LLC? What am I missing here?

Comment: Those formulas always take the last value presented as the returned value, if there is no else - what is the last value returned?

Comment: I suppose my mental model is wrong then. As a novice in Crystal, but familiar with programming, the result variable is never returned for records not matching the condition, in my mind. Following that, there would not be a value presented as the returned value, and it would default to the db value.

This seems like a backwards way to do it, to me.

Comment: Crystal Reports is usually backwards I find.  Actually if it's just backwards that's usually what passes for good.  It's usually diagonal from above, with a sharp point.

Comment: :) Well, thanks for the help. If you add your response as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I don't think I've achieved an answer, as still why is the last value the value *inside* the `if`, that is hard to reason.  You would think it was the false value of the if, or perhaps the default of the declaration - but no, it appears to be the internal value in the block that should not be executed.  Sounds like something is wrong.

Comment: I think your description that Crystal takes the last returned value regardless appears to answer my question as to why I saw the behavior I did, but raises a different question: why is it implemented that way? An interesting question, but I think stackoverflow may not be the place for it, or at least it is no longer part of this question. Just my thought.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things possible first one is you are comparing string so it can be possible you have written wrong string name 
Its a blind guess try to use below statement in "IF"

```
if GroupName ({SCD_CUSTOMER.NAME}) == "32 Bar Blues, LLC" Then
```